# IBM Notes Allows on Some Computers Only the Ability to Create an Inspection Record

Tags: lotus-notes

How can I make a specific user be able to create an Inspection Record? Only a select few can create one, I want to give the other people this ability. The people that cannot do not even have a button to select an Inspection Record under the drop down create button.[Picture of the Create Tab Without the Dropdown Inspection Record Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnjtq.png)

(The Inspection Record option in the picture is not shown yet it should look like Dock Audit instead it should say Inspection Records)

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  There are many ways to lock down security in a Notes application, and more than one way to identify a user.  You'll need to describe (and preferably show) how the application is designed and coded for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Access Control List of the application.

Press the 'Effective Access' button.

Click on the little blue person icon and use the Select Names dialog to find the name of one of the people who *can* see the Inspection Record option, click Add, and click OK. Look at the access level, the groups and roles. Take careful notes, or screen shots. (Don't forget to scroll.)

Now click on the little blue person icon again and go through the same process, this time entering the name of one of the people who *cannot* see the Inspection Record option. Compare everything against what you noted for the previous user.

One or more of the differences you see in the access level, groups, and roles is responsible for the ability to see the Inspection Record. If there's only one difference, you've found the problem. If there's more than one, you're going to need to look at the Inspection Record form in Domino Designer.

Comment: Thank you. However, this worked for another application, not Inspection Records. The Inspection Record button under the create tab only appears for certain people. What do you mean by looking at the Inspection Record within the Domino Designer? Should I change some code, and if so where do I begin?

Comment: You do not have to change the code. You need to open Domino Designer, open your application, look at the forms list, find the Inspection Record form, open it, look at the security tab in the form properties, and see what users, groups or roles are listed under the heading "Who can create documents with this form"

Comment: I got it. Thank you tremendously!